# matrix eigenvalue problem for a skew symmetric matrix of order 5

Tags: matrices, proof-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $-2+5i,\ 3i$ be two eigenvalues of a $5\times5$ skew symmetric matrix $A$. Find the other eigenvalues of $A$.

In a skew symmetric matrix the eigenvalues can be $0$ or pure imaginary.So I think the other 3 eigenvalues are $2-5i,-3i$ and $0$.
But only orthogonal matrices can have its eigenvalues existing as complex conjugates in pair. Can someone help with the answer..

Comment: Are we to assume the matrix elements are real?

Answer (score 2):

"In a skew symmetric matrix the eigenvalues can be 0 or pure imaginary."

I think this is only valid for real valued matrices.

Comment: Maybe the problem is stated in a context where the matrix is understood to be real-valued.

Comment: So is  my answer correct in the context of real valued matrix

Comment: if the matrix is real valued, then the eigenvalue -2+5i is not allowed. So no, the problem is definetly not about real valued matrices (or there is a mistake somewhere).

Answer (score 0):

Eigen values of a skew symmetric matrix can be 0 or pure imaginary.Also trace of Skew symmetric matrix=0 and det(skew symmetric matrix)=0.
This is possible only if the the other 3 eigen values are 0 ,-2-5i and -3i.